# Shell Quotations with and without environmental variables

Tags: shell, environment-variables, quotes

Here is the question:

> When the shell is reading the command-line, what is the difference between text enclosed between double quotes (") and text enclosed between single quotes (')?
>
> You need to consider two cases in which there are environment variables and there are no environmental variables.

I can't seem to find a difference, to me both cases are used the same way.

I have a bit of an understanding of hard and soft quotes but this has thrown me.

Comment: There is no difference between environment variables and normal shell variables in this context. Why do you believe otherwise?

Comment: On second thought, I think your questioner is mistaken in referring to variables in general as "environment variables". Reading it that way, your understanding that double quotes allow parameter expansion is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes normally are used where Shell variable values can be extracted.
Example:

```
my_name="prabhu"
echo "printing $my_name"
```

Output: printing prabhu

Single quotes does not print the value of a variable instead prints the given content.
Example:

```
my_name="prabhu"
echo 'printing $my_name'
```

Output: printing $my_name

Comment: Yeah that's what I understand, but I don't understand what the difference is between when environmental variables are used and when they are not. Thank you for your answer regardless.

Answer (score 0):

The question is poorly worded. It seems to be referring to variables in general, and not trying to make a distinction between "shell variables" and "environment variables" (that is, shell variables marked for export to child processes). If this is true, then the correct answer, of course, is that double-quoted strings allow parameter expansion while single-quoted strings do not.